# why isn't the file save shortcut(ctrl + s) not working in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Please Check this image]

It doesn't have the shortcut key for save option enabled.
How can I enable the shortcut key for save option in microsoft visual code.
Because ctrl + s isn't working on my desktop.

Comment: Because you've assigned it to something else?

Comment: it's literally assigned to "Save All" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your keyboard shortcuts menu by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then press <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd>), then search for **file:save** and you can double-click in the **Keybinding** column next to **File:Save** to enter whatever key combination you want:

[image: keyboard shortcuts menu screenshot]

Then you should see it in the file menu and it should work:

[image: file menu screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Like the other answers specify, you'll need to set the key binding for `File: Save` to `<ctrl|cmd>+s`, but in my case I had to set it to some other random key binding first.
I think I used `alt+shift+9`, and then `ctrl+s`

Comment: This worked. I had to assign another key binding and then when i changed back to "Ctrl+S", it worked. 

What kind of bug is this! :3

Comment: @motasimfuad Your sugestion worked for me as well, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just like the first comment on your question says, Ctrl+S seems to be assigned to 'Save All' instead. if you don't want it that way, try changing it in 'Preferences >', which is 4 blocks under the 'Save' option in the image shown in your question, and set 'Save All' to Ctrl+Shift+S and 'Save' to Ctrl+S.